# Is there a way to combine the charAt() method and includes() method instead of having to specify a certain character for charAt()?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I can make this technique work for this code?
Write a function called indexVowelTotal which accepts an array of words and returns the sum of the indexes of each word when each character is a vowel.

```js
function indexVowelTotal(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  var sum = 0;
  const vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU';
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].charAt().includes(vowels)) {
      sum += i;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(indexVowelTotal([])); // 0
console.log(indexVowelTotal(['hello'])); // 5
console.log(indexVowelTotal(['Joel', 'Elie', 'Michael', 'Matt'])); // 19
```

Comment: `(input=>[...input].filter(letter=>[...'aeiouAEIOU'].filter(vowel=>letter === vowel).length).length)('this works with one argument]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a nested loop, since you need to iterate not only over every word in the array, but also over each character in each word:

```js
function indexVowelTotal(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (const word of arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      if (/[aeiou]/i.test(word[i])) {
        sum += i;
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(indexVowelTotal([])); // 0
console.log(indexVowelTotal(['hello'])); // 5
console.log(indexVowelTotal(['Joel', 'Elie', 'Michael', 'Matt'])); // 19
```

Another approach, iterating through each word by using `.matchAll` instead of going character-by-character yourself:

```js
function indexVowelTotal(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (const word of arr) {
    for (const match of word.matchAll(/[aeiou]/ig)) {
      sum += match.index;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(indexVowelTotal([])); // 0
console.log(indexVowelTotal(['hello'])); // 5
console.log(indexVowelTotal(['Joel', 'Elie', 'Michael', 'Matt'])); // 19
```

If you wanted to use your `vowels` string:

```js
function indexVowelTotal(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  const vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU';
  for (const word of arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      if (vowels.includes(word[i])) {
        sum += i;
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(indexVowelTotal([])); // 0
console.log(indexVowelTotal(['hello'])); // 5
console.log(indexVowelTotal(['Joel', 'Elie', 'Michael', 'Matt'])); // 19
```

There's no need for the `if (arr.length === 0)` check at the beginning.

Comment: oh is that regex? I haven't learned that yet. Can you explain the /[aeiou]/i.test(word[i])?

Comment: It will match any letter in the character set `aeiou`. The `i` is the case-insensitive flag, so it matches capital letters too.

Comment: and what the does .test() do?

Comment: It returns true if the string passes the regex pattern

Comment: the other person also did /ig. if i checks for case sensitivity, what does g do?

Comment: The `g` is the global flag. It is required if you're using the expression more than once, or if you're using `.matchAll`. It's *not* required if you're using the expression only once (such as in the first snippet in the answer - the pattern expression is created, passed to `.test`, and discarded)

Answer (score 0):

One approach.

```js
function indexVowelTotal(arr) {
  let total = 0;
  for (const word of arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      if ("aeiouAEIOU".includes(word[i])) {
        total += i;
      }
    }
  }
  return total;
}
console.log(indexVowelTotal([])); // 0
console.log(indexVowelTotal(["hello"])); // 5
console.log(indexVowelTotal(["Joel", "Elie", "Michael", "Matt"])); // 19
```

Another approach by converting string to array of string using spread syntax and using
[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
function indexVowelTotal(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((total, word) => {
    total += [...word].reduce(
      (acc, ch, i) => ("aeiouAEIOU".includes(ch) ? i + acc : acc),
      0
    );
    return total;
  }, 0);
}
console.log(indexVowelTotal([])); // 0
console.log(indexVowelTotal(["hello"])); // 5
console.log(indexVowelTotal(["Joel", "Elie", "Michael", "Matt"])); // 19
```